# STUN, TURN and ICE

Tags: voip, webrtc, nat, stun

I have two PC behind the different NAT. I want to access the first PC from the second PC.
While searching over the internet, I have found the concepts of STUN, TURN and ICE.

If i run the stun client on one PC, I can find the ip and port of my PC from public internet perspective. but after that also how can i connect to other PC. How other PC will know my ip and port which is public ip and external port of my router?

Both PCs are behind Restricted cone NAT, so i think i don't need turn server functionality.
I have one PC with public IP which i can run as a STUN server.

I have read the specifications of STUN and ICE, But i am not getting the clear idea. There they are telling that there is some signalling mechanism available through which other host can know my ip and port number.

But, Exactly how?
If there is one stun server and multiple clients, then how can be decided which client need to connect with which client as no client knows about othet clients addresses?

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is, the STUN server helps the peer identify his public IP, so it does not matter how many clients are try to talk to each other, it does not care, its only job is to supply a peer with his public IP.

from what I understand, the [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) server helps you (the browser client) identify its public IP, which you would set in your [SDP](http://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/), and you pass this to the signalling server, 
 which would forward it to the other peer, similarly, the other peer would also transmit to you his sdp (the offer and answer).